# How do you fix compositing leaking in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I created a Minecraft Animation Scene with a melon in a basket. I did some compositing for another scene to make the melon glow but from a different camera angle you can see the glow from the melon leaking through the entire basket when the glow is supposed to stay inside of the basket from the melon. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is an animation, then you can keyframe your Screen fac slider

Comment: You have the render layers putting out the z-depth.  Use that in a Color -> Z Combine node.  Tweak where everything goes until you are happy.  This will either show or hide elements of your scene depending on whether they are in the foreground, or behind something.